# Cross browser issue css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

This is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/monicaphalswal/xghyz/). 
It has onHover event which changes the image. It works fine on chrome. But, doesn't work right on firefox. What to do?

This is the jQuery function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){$('.viewport').mouseenter(function(e) {
    $(this).children('a').children('span').fadeIn(200);
    }).mouseleave(function(e) {
    $(this).children('a').children('span').fadeOut(200);
});});
```

This is how it looks in chrome: [image]

And this is how it looks in firefox: [image]

Also, i have tried both solutions, with jquery and pure css.

Comment: A `mouseenter` even in Javascript has nothing to do with CSS.

Comment: Works fine on FF 25 and 26. Also, you might want to use `hover()` instead of those two functions. It's a bit easier to maintain.

Comment: Works for me too - what is your FF version and can you describe what doesn't work in detail?

Comment: works for me on FF25, what version are you on and what is the problem?

Comment: FYI, using hover event in/out handler and fadeToggle() method for mor concise code: http://jsfiddle.net/xghyz/3/

Comment: But have you same behaviour in the jsfiddle you provide?

Comment: The visual layout issue you illustrate in the picture is not at all related to the jquery code provided. If you want to fix how the label isn't over the picture, post the CSS and HTML structure for the element.

Comment: @JAL I know that. I've provided it  because it makes the hover effect. HTML & css is in the js fiddle

Comment: Which version of Firefox are you even on, did you get stuck in the non-updating 3.x branch? Both your fiddle and mine work fine in most recent versions of Chrome and Firefox... A render error like that could never result from the CSS you put in the Fiddle in a recent browser.

Comment: I see. I didn't understand the question i guess. Works okay on iOS Safari, btw!

Comment: Ok this is so stupid of me. i had mistakenly added css for #user-image too and then forgot about it completely. It was the reason for this issue. I'm feeling sorry.

Answer (score 4):

Delete all your Javascript and replace with pure CSS:

```
.viewport a span {
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity 200ms;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 200ms;
}
.viewport:hover a span {
    opacity:1;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/xghyz/2/).

Comment: Completely disagree. Yes, CSS transitions are nice, *no* they should not be used without fall-back for important information. Since the information provided inside the span is important, users with older browsers will not be able to see that information. It would be different if a transition does not supply important information and it's mere eye-candy, but that's not the case here.

Comment: Erm, if the browser doesn't support transitions, this will just work without the fade. There will be **no loss of information**. There's a bigger chance someone has disabled Javascript than having a browser that doesn't support `:hover` behaviours, and without JS it **will be broken**, hence this solution is **more** resilient than JS-based. You just might need to patch in a fallback to `display` for ancient IE-versions that do not support `opacity`.

Comment: Right and wrong. I was not talking about the transition itself, but about the `opacity` property. Which is not supported by older browsers. At least provide a `filter()` "fall-back". Here are equivalents: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-opacity/

Comment: Again, no fallback required. IE8 and older may not support `opacity` but in that case the element will *always be visible* as default. Again, no loss of information, a fallback to `filter` or `display` is just stylish for ancient browsers, not strictly *required*.

Comment: I realise now that I've been wrong in the logic I was following. (Unfortunately I cannot un-downvote). I just don't understand why you would not even write 4 lines of code more to give a better experience to people that are stuck with IE8 (couldn't care less about 7 though). Now, there is no hover effect/feedback at all on older browsers. Using an `opacity` equivalent will at least provide the similar experience and give a user feedback on his input - the basics of a good GUI.

Comment: @Rob Probably because the question was not at all clear from the beginning, before she provided an image to illustrate a problem - that is not even related to the Fiddle she provided.

Comment: girls girls girls... your both pretty. (j/k) in all seriousness, don't forget to add the vendor prefixes for older/different browsers. this should reduce the failing browsers to a minimal level. and since it is browser rendered there is minimal delay on page load.

Comment: @phlume [only webkit required and I added it](http://caniuse.com/css-transitions).

Comment: @BramVanroy no prob, I wouldn't have kept explaining if I considered it just another flamewar  :)  I'm on Phlume's end of things - if we keep supporting IE8 as developers, it will never go away. I develop for up to date platforms, and while I try to always [gracefully degrade](http://www.css3.info/graceful-degradation/) for old browsers I don't implement pixel-perfect support for a 4.5 year old browser like IE8 unless a customer is paying extra. Also, you can un-downvote by clicking it again.

Comment: -o ? -moz ? -ms ? I was speaking of older browsers not on an auto release/update schedule.

Comment: @Phlume click the link under that comment. Neither [opacity](http://caniuse.com/css-opacity) nor [transition](http://caniuse.com/css-transitions) requires prefix unless you go more than major 4 versions back. Graceful degradation has its limits imho.

Comment: The problem is, imo, that there are still a quite lot of people (and especially businesses) that are using Windows XP and unfortunately, IE9 requires [Vista or higher](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/internet-explorer/products/ie-9/system-requirements). This is why I keep supporting IE8 for now as best as I can. Obviously, I will not support it within a year or two when the market share of Windows 7 and 8 have grown. Also, un-downvoting is not possible: "You last voted on this answer 1 hour ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited." I'm sorry.

Comment: Heh no worries, I'm way over my daily rep cap anyway already. As for XP, [that problem is solving itself](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/endofsupport.aspx). As said, I don't invest extra time in 4.5 year old browsers unless a client pays extra, I have the same stance on an 11.5 (!) year old OS. Graceful degradation sure, but extra effort - let them go install Chrome, it works fine on XP with all the latest CSS effects.